# TintColor (Run Time Attribute) in Xcode8 \ iOS 10

Tags: swift, user-interface, ios10, xcode8, tintcolor

In the IB the `tintColor` Runtime attribute is working with Xcode 7.3.1 & iOS 9 But in Xcode 8 and iOS 10 it doesn't  ....anyone know whats the new command or anyway to make this work again?